# Laravel 9 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm having this error that comes out when I try to make an insert to db

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
> update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
> (`chiocciolina`.`orders_detail`, CONSTRAINT
> `orders_detail_order_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES
> `orders_grid` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Table 1:

```
        Schema::create('orders_grid', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('id_agente')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->tinyText('canale');
        $table->integer('codice_cliente')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('codice_destinazione')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamp('data_ordine');
        $table->date('data_richiesta')->nullable();
        $table->tinyText('tipologia',1);
        $table->integer('edi_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('edi_company',5)->nullable();
        $table->string('edi_doctype',2)->nullable();
        $table->integer('jde_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('jde_company',5)->nullable();
        $table->string('jde_doctype',2)->nullable();
        $table->integer('stato_ordine')->default(0);
        $table->decimal('total_order',8,2)->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->text('note_consegna')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Table 2:

```
        Schema::create('orders_detail', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('order_id')->constrained('orders_grid')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('nr_riga')->unsigned();
        $table->string('codice_articolo',25);
        $table->integer('quantita')->unsigned();
        $table->decimal('prezzo',6,4)->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

What's wrong in this code? I followed this documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

P.S. Also why when i set a column to float on migration it converts it to double in mysql?

Thanks for help

Comment: Instead of `integer`, you want to use `bigIncrements` since that's what Laravel uses for `id()` under the hood. The key and foreign key columns need to have matching datatypes.

Comment: Which engine (InnoDB, MyISAM) are you using on the tables in your database?

Comment: @Peppermintology im using InnoDB

Comment: @geertjanknapen $table->foreignId('order_id') has to match with the primary key id of order_grid table